# Concurrent Job Scheduling and Processing Assignment trouble

Tags: c++, multithreading, operating-system

I am taking an operating systems theory class and one of the tasks for an assignment was this:
As the interactive job scheduler main(), jobDispatch() and runJob() are running simultaneously, there is a concurrency problem that will cause this program to fail occasionally (depending on how many CPUs/Cores) that the running machine has.

Modify this program to ensure it will run on any CPU/Core configuration.
Hint:  You'll need to identify the common resource(s) those 3 functions use.  Then use mutual exclusion feature of C++ to protect the resource(s).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;
static const int numJobsMax = 3;  // maximum jobs allowed to run simulataneously
int numJobsRunning = 0;  // check # of jobs currently running
bool programEndFlag = false;  // send program end signal to all threads
int lastJobID = 1;  // unique job ID starts with 1
enum status { jobReadyToRun, jobRunning, jobToBeStopped };  // job running status

// job structure to keep job information
struct job {
    string jobName;  // name of the job
    int jobID;  // unique # for job ID
    status jobStatus = jobReadyToRun;  // initialize status
    int jobProcessTime = 15;  // default process time = 10 sec
};

vector<job*> jobQueue;  // system queue for user created jobs

/* function prototyping */
void jobDispatch();  // dispath job from the job queue in the background (thread)
void runJob(job*);  // run job as a thread
void batchJobs();  // run a predefined batch job queue

int main() {
    int choice;
    job* jobPtr;

    /* run Job Dispatcher in the background as a thread */
    std::thread t = std::thread(jobDispatch);
    t.detach();

    /* Allow user to schedule or delete jobs */
    programEndFlag = false;
    do {
        cout << "\nJob Scheduling Options:\n";
        cout << "1: Start a new job\n";
        cout << "2: Display job queue\n";
        cout << "99: Exit\n";
        cout << "Please enter your choice (#): ";
        cin >> choice;

        switch (choice) {
        case 1:
            jobPtr = new job;
            cout << "Enter Job Name: ";
            cin >> jobPtr->jobName;
            jobPtr->jobID = lastJobID++;
            jobPtr->jobStatus = jobReadyToRun;  // set status to ReadyToRun for jobDispatch()
            jobQueue.push_back(jobPtr);  // push new job to job queue
            break;
        case 2:
            cout << "\nNumber of Jobs: " << jobQueue.size() << endl;
            for (unsigned int i = 0; i < jobQueue.size(); i++) {
                jobPtr = jobQueue[i];
                cout << "Name=" << jobPtr->jobName << " ";
                cout << "ID=" << jobPtr->jobID << " ";
                if (jobPtr->jobStatus == jobRunning) cout << "Status=Running." << endl;
                if (jobPtr->jobStatus == jobReadyToRun) cout << "Status=ReadyToRun." << endl;
                if (jobPtr->jobStatus == jobToBeStopped) cout << "Status=ToBeStopped." << endl;
            }
            break;
        }
    } while (choice != 99);

    std::cout << "\nMain Program ended\n";
    programEndFlag = true;
    system("pause");

    // remove job files before exit program
    system("del Job*");
    system("del stop_Job*");
    return 0;
}

// dispath job from the job queue in the background (thread)
void jobDispatch() {
    int activeJobs;
    
    // this thread loops forever until error occurs or program ends
    while (true) {
        if (programEndFlag) break;  // End this thread when user exit program

        // Validate # of running jobs are less than maximum allowed
        activeJobs = 0;
        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < jobQueue.size(); i++)
            if (jobQueue[i]->jobStatus == jobRunning)
                activeJobs++;
        if (activeJobs > numJobsMax) {
            cout << "Error: more jobs running than maximum allowed" << endl;
            return;
        }

        // Run jobs with status ReadyToRun
        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < jobQueue.size(); i++) {
            if (activeJobs < numJobsMax && jobQueue[i]->jobStatus == jobReadyToRun) {
                activeJobs++;
                std::thread t = std::thread(runJob, jobQueue[i]);
                t.detach();
                jobQueue[i]->jobStatus = jobRunning;
            }
        }

        // Terminate jobs with status jobToBeStopped
        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < jobQueue.size(); i++) {
            if (jobQueue[i]->jobStatus == jobToBeStopped) {
                activeJobs--;
                string jobFile, cmdLine;
                jobFile = "Job" + to_string(jobQueue[i]->jobID) + ".txt";
                cmdLine = "ren " + jobFile + " " + "stop_" + jobFile;
                system((cmdLine).c_str());
                jobQueue.erase(jobQueue.begin() + i);
            }
        }
    }
}

// run job as a thread
void runJob(job* jobPtr) {
    string jobFile, cmdLine;
    jobFile = "Job" + to_string(jobPtr->jobID) + ".txt";
    ofstream outFile(jobFile);
    outFile << "Job" << jobPtr->jobID << " - " << jobPtr->jobName << " is running ..." << endl;

    this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(jobPtr->jobProcessTime));  // doing something
    outFile << "Job completed." << endl;
    outFile.close();
    jobPtr->jobStatus = jobToBeStopped;  // set job status so it will be removed from queue
}
```

The common resource that the professor is talking about is the job queue(this is what he said in the lecture) at first I thought it was as simple as adding a .lock and .unlock(we have had assignments that was as simple as adding 2 lines of code so I figured he might just be trying to stump us again) to the void jobDispatch() but that was giving me the error E0300 a pointer to a bound function may only be used to call the function
This is what I add along with calling the #include  and initializing mutex Locker;

```
void jobDispatch() {
    int activeJobs;
    Locker.lock;
    // this thread loops forever until error occurs or program ends
    while (true) {
        if (programEndFlag) break;  // End this thread when user exit program

        // Validate # of running jobs are less than maximum allowed
        activeJobs = 0;
        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < jobQueue.size(); i++)
            if (jobQueue[i]->jobStatus == jobRunning)
                activeJobs++;
        if (activeJobs > numJobsMax) {
            cout << "Error: more jobs running than maximum allowed" << endl;
            return;
        }

        // Run jobs with status ReadyToRun
        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < jobQueue.size(); i++) {
            if (activeJobs < numJobsMax && jobQueue[i]->jobStatus == jobReadyToRun) {
                activeJobs++;
                std::thread t = std::thread(runJob, jobQueue[i]);
                t.detach();
                jobQueue[i]->jobStatus = jobRunning;
            }
        }

        // Terminate jobs with status jobToBeStopped
        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < jobQueue.size(); i++) {
            if (jobQueue[i]->jobStatus == jobToBeStopped) {
                activeJobs--;
                string jobFile, cmdLine;
                jobFile = "Job" + to_string(jobQueue[i]->jobID) + ".txt";
                cmdLine = "ren " + jobFile + " " + "stop_" + jobFile;
                system((cmdLine).c_str());
                jobQueue.erase(jobQueue.begin() + i);
            }
        }
        Locker.unlock;
        //this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(5));  // DELAY 5 sec to AVOID crash (a temporary fix given to us to see exactly how the program works but we are unable to use as our solution)
    }
  }
}
```

The only solution that I think would help is https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/mutex/unlock which Im unable to figure out how to implement into this assignment. Im probably overthinking this entire thing and my brain is just absolutely fried at this point but I have used the basic .lock and .unlock as I used above before and it worked fine. Any help/tips/advice/hints are much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

> that was giving me the error E0300 a pointer to a bound function may only be used to call the function

`()` is missing in the function calls.
It should be `Locker.lock()` and `Locker.unlock()`

I also suggest to reconsider the place to put the lock.

There is only 1 thread running the function `jobDispatcher()`, it is always single-threaded. You may think in this way, if `jobQueue` is the common resource, there are multiple threads accessing and modifying `jobQueue` simultaneously, which part of the code will cause concurrency problem? Lock the minimum code that is needed can increase the efficiency.